# PHP date timezone producing unexpected result off by an hour

Tags: php, date, datetime

This timezone problem is driving me crazy and hoping someone can put me in my place fast as it's likely super simple

```
$timezone = 'EST';
$datetimenow = new DateTime("Now", new DateTimeZone($timezone));

$today = $datetimenow->format("m/d/Y"); // = 03/26/2021

// FOR LOOP
$filter = $today .' '.$details->data->time['start']; // where start = 8:30 PM

// END FOR LOOP

$datetimeevent = new DateTime($filter, new DateTimeZone($timezone));    
// datetimeevent print_r = correct = 
DateTime Object
(
   [date] => 2021-03-26 20:30:00.000000
   [timezone_type] => 2
   [timezone] => EST
)

$filter = $datetimeevent->getTimestamp();
// $filter = 1616808600
// 1616808600 =
//String: 
//GMT: Saturday, March 27, 2021 1:30:00 AM
//Your time zone: Friday, March 26, 2021 9:30:00 PM GMT-04:00 DST
```

huh?  how is 8:30 becoming 9:30 on what should be a straight up conversion?

Comment: Current timezone is not "EST", it's "EDT". Using unambiguous time zone names like `America/New York` will avoid this problem.

Comment: Thank you sir. Appreciate the guidance.  Normally that's what I do but messed it up today